# using iTextSharp.tool.xml not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I Spend 3 days why adding namespace **using iTextSharp.tool.xml not working** not working. I already put itextsharp.dll in bin folders. Other related namespaces are working. Plz help.

Answer (score 9):

I just had the same problem, just run the command below in the *Package Manager Console*. Felt like an easier solution and it solved the problem for me!

```
Install-Package iTextSharp.xmlworker
```

Answer (score 7):

Found Solution
I downloaded itextsharp.xmlworker.dll and put in bin folder. It worked

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/

Comment: You should also remember to add reference in project.

Comment: Yes. Reference is added to project in case it is web application. For WebSites it work without adding References.

Comment: This doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score -2):

use this namespace your problem is solved.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
```

this namespace for itextsharp.dll in use for PDF.

Comment: I need iTextSharp.tool.xml  or iTextSharp.tool to run. is there separate dll for this namespace

Comment: This answer is wrong. It doesn't answer the question: the question is about XML Worker; this answer is about obsolete functionality in iTextSharp.